# How do I prevent search engine crawlers from indexing a domain on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-ecs, amazon-route53

We have a staging environment running on a `.dev` domain alongside our production environment running on another domain.

**Is there any way to prevent our `.dev` domain from being indexed?**

I don't want our staging website to be found on Google when searching for the product.

The domain is being hosted on AWS, using Route 53 with Cloudfront as a CDN.

Applications are hosted on ECS with a load balancer in front.

Comment: Is Cloudfront routed to an S3 bucket?

Comment: Nope! cloudfront origin is routed to a loadbalancer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you have permission to add files to the domain e.g. S3 bucket, EC2 instance, ECS container instance etc., place a [`robots.txt`](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/intro) file in the root folder**.

Set the contents as:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Make sure to allow **public read access** to the file (object) so search engine crawlers belonging to Google, Bing etc. can find and process it.

This will prevent bots from indexing your files, and thus your domain.

---

Please note that if your production domain points to the staging website, Google's crawler can *still* index your staging website as the search engine crawler will *crawl* from your prod. website to your staging one.

In this case, `robots.txt` won't always prevent the website from being indexed & you'll need the [`X-Robots-Tag: noindex`](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/block-indexing#http-response-header) HTTP response header returned for the files your CloudFront distribution returns.

In that case, you need a more complex solution such as using [AWS Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/) to add the headers if you don't have a web server serving your requests.

That would definitely prevent indexing by Google regardless of if the page is linked to or not.

Comment: The deployment is on ECS, so I'm going to put the robots.txt in the root directory of my project basically. I'll give it a shot thanks for your comment.

Comment: You're welcome, that should work as well, let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: something I wonder is that if I put it in root of the project it's going to affect production as well because. they are on two different branch and eventually when we merge develop with main the robots.txt file is going to be available in production as well.

Comment: Keep the `robots.txt` out of git or add it dynamically as part of your pipeline which deploys to ECS if possible?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ELB, you can add a listener rule to return a fixed response for your `robots.txt`.

[image: Example configuration for rule set up, checking if host id yoursite.dev and path is /robots.txt]

This means you do not have to have code within your site to distinguish between staging and production, and will allow you to keep your production version clean.